# Extracting specific data from multiple text files to excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, txt

I have mutiple text files that contains data like [file1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hERaO.jpg) ,[file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1QHC.jpg),[file3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OZAU.jpg). Its just an example, I am wondering how to populate specific data in an Excel sheet like this [excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMJlz.jpg)

I am new to learning python and the combination of text to excel through python that's why finding it hard to approch

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is to Parse and write a new File in the csv File format for the use in excel

file1 -> PythonScript.py -> excel.csv

File Parser Python Tutorial [Tutorial](https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/)

The .csv File looks like this. You have a header and the data seperated with commas.

excel.csv:

```
Name,Data
hibiscus_3,54k
hibiscus_7,67k
Rose_3,87MB
```

Hope i could help you